# Is the SQL Server double precision data type an implementation of the IEEE 754 standard?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find the most accurate MSSQL/Oracle mapping for the Java double datatype. **[Java double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)** conforms to the IEEE 754 standard and Oracle's **[BINARY_DOUBLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00209)** seems to be an exact match. The SQL Server documentation for the **[double precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)** data type is very succinct though, with no mention of standards conformance. Considering that it uses 8 bytes, it might be an implementation of the IEEE 754 double precision ...

Comment: MS SQL Server has problems with IEEE 754 floats, mainly that in SQL 2005+ (It works in SQL 2000 for some reason) you can't store +/- Infinity or NaN. What is your intended use of the data?

Comment: Big integers, larger than bigint. I don't want to use more than 8 bytes for storage and I'm OK with the truncation introduced by double precision.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation in SQL Server (through SQL Server 2014 at time of writing) is IEEE 754 compliant *except* for lack of support for constants NaN and +/- Infinity. If all you want is to be able to store a massively large number and do not mind all the rounding and precision baggage that the double precision data type (officially declared as DOUBLE PRECISION, FLOAT(53), or just FLOAT) brings with it then you should be OK.